# How to apply color on vector based on specific property with BlenderGIS?

Tags: blender, shapefile

I'm using an imported shapefile on BlenderGIS and I want to make a choropleth based on the values of one of the shapefile's attributes (called specific property in Blender). This related issue on the github repo is exaclty what I'm looking for! https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/discussions/772 .

I'm super new to the Blender IDE so I'm not sure to manipulate things yet